# Delegate, why the key word event works with operator ' = '?

Tags: c#, delegates

I know that the keyword 'event' associated to a delegate variable allow you just to use the operator += and -=, and the operator = is forbidden. I was trying to verify this behaviour, but at the line `mydelegate = p.stampaPropUmano;`not only Visual Studio doesn't signale me an error, but also all works perfectly. stampaPropUmano and stampaPropAnimale are two methods of the class Umano and Animale respectively.

Do you know the reason? Please let me know if the keyword "event" give other properties.. In my documentation I found just the property that I said before. Regards

```
namespace csharpWPFevent
    { 
    public delegate void delegato(int index=7);

public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public event delegato mydelegate;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Persona p = new Persona();
            p.Costa = "Paulo";
            p.Cognome = "Sousa";
            Animale a = new Animale("Fufficus", "Cane spaziale");

            mydelegate = p.stampaPropUmano; // ??????? Why?
            mydelegate += a.stampaPropAnimale;
        }

        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            mydelegate(1);   
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That restriction is for clients of the class that declared the `event`, the class itself can use `=`. E.g

```
public delegate void delegato(int index=7);

public class Foo
{
    public event delegato myEvent;

    public void Bar()
    {
        // no error
        myEvent = (int i) => {};
    }
}

void Main()
{
    var foo = new Foo();
    // The event 'Foo.myEvent' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -= (except when used from within the type 'Foo')
    foo.myEvent = (int i) => {};        
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A c# event is a multicast delegate. That is, a delegate with multiple targets.

All the `event` keyword does is ensure that classes that do not own the delegate can only use the `+=` and `-=` operators upon the field.

By using the `=` operator, you are overwriting the value of `delegato`, assigning it to `p.stampaPropUmano`.

Answer (score 1):

Well. Let's clarify it a bit more :

**Delegates :**

```
   Action a = null;
   a = MyMethod;  // overwrites value of a with one method;
   a += MyMethod; // assigns method to a (not changing anything apart of it)
   a -= MyMethod; // removes method from a
```

**Events :**

Inside of class declaration :

```
   public event Action MyEvent;
```

Inside of class ctor or any other method :

```
   MyEvent = new Action(MyMethod);  // assign the event with some delegate;
```

In same or any other class :

```
   myClassInstance.MyEvent += new Action(MyOtherMethod); // subscribing for the event;
   myClassInstance.MyEvent -= new Action(MyOtherMethod); // unsubscribing for the event;
```

So whenever you the event is fired it calls the method (or methods) on the delegate that is subscribed to it or is set explicitly inside the class where this event was created.

You may ask: why is not possible to assign value to event directly from other class?

Because it would be unsafe to use events in this case.

Let's assume that it's possible to assign some value for events from some other class and consider the scenario :

```
Class A has event - > MyEvent;

Class B subscribes for event with += 
Class C subscribes for event with += 
Class D changes MyEvent value to `null`

Event is invoked in Class A, but it's set to null and exception is thrown
```